# Is there any way i can get device token for fcm firebase push notifications for Ios users

Tags: ios, iphone, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting device tokens and the flow to get notifications are working on windows and android but not working for ios devices how do i get device token for ios. I am using laravel 10 to send push notifications via firebase FCM to multiple devices.

I have tried high priority and json too but it wont work for ios as I read safari now get push notifications after ios 16.4 but I didnt get it, it is not working either, I dont want a native app for this.